# Code to find the proper index comparing 3 values for max one

Tags: java, algorithm, array

I have an algorithm and the idea is to move over an array choosing as index the index of the neighboring cell that has the max value.
I.e.

if array[i + 1][j + 1] has the largest value among the 3 then move there.

[image]

I have 2 versions of this, but I think it can be cleaner.

version 1:

```
int maxI = i + 1;  
int maxJ = j + 1;  
if(array[i + 1][j] > array[maxI][maxJ]){   
    maxI = i + 1;  
    maxJ = j;  
}  
if(array[i][j + 1] > array[maxI][maxJ]){  
    maxI = i;  
    maxJ = j + 1;  
}
i = maxI;  
j = maxJ;
```

version 2:

```
if(LCS[i + 1][j + 1] > LCS[i][j + 1] && LCS[i + 1][j + 1] > LCS[i + 1][j]){   
    i++;  
    j++;  
}  
else{  
    if(LCS[i][j + 1] > LCS[i + 1][j]){  
        j++;  
    }  
    else{i++;}  
}
```

Both versions occur in a `while` loop which I omitted for clarity.
How can these versions become better?

Comment: In *Version 1* you can remove the line ` maxI = i + 1; ` in the first `if`-block, because it does not do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to follow the second version. I've extracted out some helper variables:

```
    final int b = array[i][j + 1];
    final int c = array[i + 1][j];
    final int d = array[i + 1][j + 1];

    if (d > b && d > c) {
        i = i + 1;
        j = j + 1;
    } else if (b > c) {
        j = j + 1;
    } else {
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

It seems a little bit readable for me but to be honest I'm not completely satisfied with the result.